# Add textbox in Checkboxlist for particular item checked WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I am creating a application using WPF. I am able to bind Checkboxlist by using the below code:
**XAML:**

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="defaultTemplate">
        <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="lstcheckbox" Checked="lstcheckbox_Checked_1" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked}" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Checked}" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="lstcheckbox" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource Template1}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:SomeTemplateSelector x:Key="SomeTemplateSelector" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource defaultTemplate}"
                                                             Template1="{StaticResource Template1}">

    </local:SomeTemplateSelector>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <dxd:DockLayoutManager x:Name="dockManager" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <dxd:LayoutGroup Caption="Review Checklist" Orientation="Vertical" ShowCaption="True" GroupBorderStyle="Group" CaptionAlignMode="AlignInGroup">
            <dxd:LayoutControlItem>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="8,5,5,5">Safety Equipment</TextBlock>
                    <!--<ListView x:Name="lstSafEquip" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SomeTemplateSelector}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDataTemplate}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="200" />-->
                    <ListView x:Name="lstSafEquip" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SomeTemplateSelector}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="200" />
                </Grid>
            </dxd:LayoutControlItem>
        </dxd:LayoutGroup>
    </dxd:DockLayoutManager>
</Grid>
```

**CS:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindCheckBoxs(lstSafEquip);
    }

    private void BindCheckBoxs(ListView lst)
    {
        try
        {
            ObservableCollection<Data> Source = new ObservableCollection<Data> { new Data(1, "Apple"), new Data(2, "Mango"), new Data(3, "Others"), new Data(3, "Banana"), new Data(3, "Grapes") };
            lst.ItemsSource = Source;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }

}


public class SomeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Template1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Data _Item = (Data)item;
        if (_Item.Name == "Others")
        {
            return Template1;
        }
        return DefaultTemplate; 
    }
}
```

**DATA.CS:**

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public Data(int _ID, string _Name)
    {
        ID = _ID;
        Name = _Name;
        Checked = false;
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

I want to add textbox just below the checkboxlist item **Others** when user will checked this item.
By using the above code trigger enter textbox for each item when i checked.
[image]

please let me know where i am going wrong. I will try my best to provide more info if needed.

Comment: Just place a TextBox there and bind it's visibility to the Checkbox's IsChecked property....

Comment: @Heyyou Yes you are right. How i can do this?

Comment: @Barptad I alresy did this. But hidden textbox taking space between items.

Comment: @Barptad Are you able to implement this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After merging all suggestions and comments. I reached on the solution.

**XAML:**

Added textbox in default template

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="defaultTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="lstcheckbox" Checked="lstcheckbox_Checked_1" Unchecked="lstcheckbox_Checked_1" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtOther" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible}" Text="test" Width="100"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**XAML.CS:**

```
  private void lstcheckbox_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Data some = (sender as CheckEdit).DataContext as Data;
        if (some.Name.Contains("Others"))
        {
            some.Visible = ToggleVisibility(some.Visible);
        }
    }
    private Visibility ToggleVisibility(Visibility visibility)
    {
        return visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

**DATA.CS:**

Added visible property and inherited with INotifyPropertyChanged to track change in property in Data.cs

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Visibility _visible;
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    //public Visibility Visible { get; set; }

    public Visibility Visible
    {
        get { return this._visible; }
        set
        {
            this._visible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Visible");
        }

    }

    public Data(int _ID, string _Name,Visibility _visible)
    {
        ID = _ID;
        Name = _Name;
        Visible = _visible;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**SomeTemplateSelector.CS**

```
 public class SomeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate OthersTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return DefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 2):

From what i understood from your post and comments:
Add a TextBox as Barptad suggested but use a BooleanToVisibilityCollapsed Converter as stated below:

**BooleanToVisibilityCollapsedConverter.cs:**

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityCollapsedConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return ((bool) value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) { 
        //never used 
        return null;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="defaultTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="lstcheckbox" Checked="lstcheckbox_Checked_1" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked}" />
        <TextBox Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=lstcheckbox}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you use Visibility.Hidden the textbox is not visible but still takes place.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Me If I am worng!
U want to show textbox only under "Others" item when it is checked.

For the scenario mentioned above u need to have two different templates that changes on the value of item.

For e.g if the item is "Others" it should have template that have a text box just below check box which is only shown when checkbox is checked otherwise collapsed.

for the second type of items it should have different template even if it is checked no textbox should be displayed under it.

(Step 1) Create a Template Selector

```
public class ValueDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate OthersTemplate { get; set; } 

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
        {
            DataTemplate template = DefaultTemplate;

            CheckList data = item as CheckList;
            if (data.Description.Contains("Others"))
            {
                template = OthersTemplate;
            }

            return template;
        }

    }
```

Reference assembly in your file.
(Step 3) Create two templates as given below

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Description}"></CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="OthersTemplate">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Path=Description}"></CheckBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="othersTextBox">
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:ValueDataTemplateSelector x:Key="CheckListTemplateSelector"
                                        DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"
                                         OthersTemplate="{StaticResource OthersTemplate}"/>


    </Window.Resources>
```